# Wireless DC Motor Speed Control

Tags: wireless, dc-motor

I am looking at purchasing this [24V 110RPM 1amp DC motor](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/151111608896?var=450202244538&ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWAX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1423.l2649) with a speed controller [like this one](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/PWM-miniature-DC-motor-speed-controller-DC-converter-/161122995449?tpos=unknow&talgo=origal&ttype=price&tfrom=151111608896) that the listing recommends.

I have been doing some research into controlling linear actuators via wireless, and some people are doing that with a simple garage door wireless controller being modified.

My question is, how do I wirelessly control the speed of a DC motor in a similar "easy" fashion? All I've been able to come up with is perhaps controlling a servo wirelessly, but that starts to get a bit complicated when they are talking about XBee wireless and programming PIC chips (which I have never done).

Any help pushing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You should probably comment about your experience level in electronics and programming, to give an idea of what solutions might be in scope.

Comment: "Very little" is probably the best way to put it.... lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a first pass:

1. Check out sites like Pololu for DC motor controllers.
2. These can be easily connected to Arduino, and libraries and demo code are readily available.

ie: no need to run a servo to turn the knob of that "recommended" motor controller.

1. Various wireless solutions for Arduino are available, again with libraries and demo code.

It's a pretty easy path to gluing this together, so long as you have at least some programming background.

---

As an alternative, there are DC motor control accessories to connect up to R/C (radio control) gear, like these:

http://www.robotshop.com/en/rc-motor-controllers.html

... which might be more turn-key at some cost in getting it to do exactly what you want.  It seems like you are in the neighborhood of robot remote control, so that's probably the place to sniff around.

-- Graham

Comment: Thanks for that. I will do some research into that avenue. Thanks.

Comment: Hope you saw my edit.